# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to use Mongo Template with spring but it gives **InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException**

My Main Class is

```
package com.spring.mongodb.main;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.spring.mongodb.model.Person;

public class SpringDataMongoDBMain {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    public static final String PERSON_COLLECTION = "mycol";
    public static final String MONGO_HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int MONGO_PORT = 27017;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Mongo mongo = new MongoClient(MONGO_HOST, MONGO_PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to MongoDB");
            MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(mongo, DB_NAME);
            System.out.println("Connected to database");
            Person p = new Person("100", "ABC", "GRG PQR");
            mongoOps.createCollection(PERSON_COLLECTION);
            mongoOps.insert(p, PERSON_COLLECTION);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My Model Class is:

```
package com.spring.mongodb.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String i, String n, String a) {
        this.id = i;
        this.name = n;
        this.address = a;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + "::" + name + "::" + address;
    }
}
```

and my Spring.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" id="mongo" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="mydb" mongo-ref="mongo"
        id="mongoDbFactory" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.mongodb.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoOps" ref="mongoTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I run the above code it gives following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
    at com.spring.mongodb.main.SpringDataMongoDBMain.main(SpringDataMongoDBMain.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more
```

I have added following jars:

```
mongodb-driver-3.1.1.jar
mongodb-driver-core-3.1.1.jar
spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar
```

I tried debuging the code it shows error when it comes to MongoOperations object creation and terminates.What I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some jars (spring-tx, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-expression, etc..)

Have a look at maven to manage your dependencies